# "Checkout Method" step is not displaying under onepage checkout

Tags: onepage-checkout

Before "1.Checkout Method" step was displaying under onepage checkout.

[image]

than we did lot of customizations, now its "1.Checkout Method" step is not displaying.

we reverted most of the customizations related to checkout, but still its not displaying.

[image]

System > configuration > Sales > checkout

[image]

Is there any way to find what is the reason behind this ?

Comment: With out checking  your source code,it cannot be possible to detect the issue

Comment: @AmitBera is it possible to find on which files  code i need to look?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to the rest of the options not showing after?

Comment: @07lodgeT i think i did't got solution, i forgotten as it was asked before 3 years, you can post new question....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix!

add `#checkout-step-billing { display: block !important; }` to your css.

It will show the first step.

Comment: now its showing option to enter information under billing information as http://prntscr.com/aqse5e, but its not showing 1st step.

Comment: Try to inspect the id of of first block then change `checkout-step-billing` with that id

Comment: please check checkout here : [Not working](http://hotwheelstoys.in/3/em0113-full-package/index.php/)  & [working](http://hotwheelstoys.in/4/em0113-full-package/index.php/)

Comment: check the console error

Comment: console : `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)`

Comment: TypeError: jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def] is not a function
 

...uad",swing:function(e,t,n,r,i){return jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def](e,t,n,r,i...

 
jquery.....min.js (line 69, col 82)
TypeError: jQuery(...).viewPC is not a function
 

if(jQuery('body').viewPC()){

 
em0113.js (line 372, col 6)
TypeError: jQuery(...).csslider is not a function
 

jQuery('#slider_storeview').csslider({

Comment: this error related to [site](http://hotwheelstoys.in/4/em0113-full-package/index.php/) but here, 1st step is displaying , but in this [site](http://hotwheelstoys.in/3/em0113-full-package/index.php/) , its not displaying